# Nearly all cpu time usage of md command

Tags: git, ubuntu, process, kill, userdel

My ubuntu server 17.10 has been running normally. But today I find that the md command of git user occupies nearly all the cpu time somehow. 
In my first try, I want to kill the process of md command, so I run:

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

But after I kill the process of md, a new process of md occurs at once.

I doubt that the cause of the problem might be the git user, so I deleted user git by force:

```
sudo userdel git -f
```

The user git was deleted successfully but the md command remains, and the user becomes 1082 instead of git.
Then I doubt that another reason might be the git command, so I remove the git:

```
sudo apt -y remove git
```

But the 1012 user and the md command remains.
The output of top is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvqLC.jpg).
And there isn't an md or madam command installed on my ubuntu server:

```
root@amax:~# md
-bash: md: command not found
root@amax:/# madam
-bash: madam: command not found
```

What is the strangest is that when I add the user git again, the owner of the md command becomes git again! [This](https://imgur.com/a/VqyrB) is the new output of top. There must be some links between git and md but I can't figure it out.
So what could the reason be? How to kill the md command permanently? Thank you!

Comment: Git does not have an "md" command. There is [a /dev/md device](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/md.4.html) but it's normally managed via `mdadm`.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: I read the docs but don't find the method.

Comment: The md device would not create an `md` process, and processes for devices are normally running as root, so I don't think they're related. This `md` command must be something you, or one of your users, installed. Find out who and why and talk with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consistent trying, finally I find a way to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt -y install cpulimit
sudo cpulimit -l <percentage of cpu limit> -p <process id>
```

The tool cpulimit can limit the percentage of cpu usage of a specified process.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a miner. There [are](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381250) [a couple of](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/unable-to-kill-md-process-4175619359/) [reports](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175686/monero-miner-in-info-directory-a-worm-signature) about "md" executable in wrong folder that is actually a miner installed by some adversary. You should check it out.